# How to use spinner int value to programatically add views?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

Here is the relevant code:

```
mspin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
Integer[] items = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
mspin.setAdapter(adapter);

RG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

mspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        int TYPE = Integer.parseInt(mspin.getSelectedItem().toString());

        setRadios(TYPE);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});

public void setRadios(int mk) {

    for(int i=0; i==mk; i++){

        RadioButton bg = new RadioButton(this);
        bg.setText("hello, this is mk");

        RG.addView(bg);

    }

}
```

I am trying to get an int value from a spinner and then add that many RadioButtons to the RadioGruop RG. However, when I run the code it does nothing when I click on a spinner value.

Comment: You must add the radiobuttons to a radiogroup and then add the radiogroup to a layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method:

```
public void setRadios(int number) {

    for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) { //add to first row
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
        rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
            rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
            rdbtn.setText("Radio " + rdbtn.getId());
            rg.addView(rdbtn);
        }
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(rg);
    }

  }
```

in XML:

```
<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:orientation="vertical" />
```

you are not adding `radiobutton` to the `viewgroup`

Comment: I have already declared a radio group in my xml file. would I still need to make a new RadioGroup?

Comment: try the code ..see if it works and hide your xml radiogroup

Comment: put a toast message to see if u get the correct value: after selecting:`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(TYPE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: what should be substituted into the last line of code for R.id.radiogroup , as there is no radioGroup, unless referring to my initial radioGroup?

Comment: thanks! works great. however, is there a way to make the buttons appear underneath one another.

Answer (score 0):

```
int TYPE = Integer.parseInt(mspin.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

this is wrong try the below code. it will worked .

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int TYPE=Integer.parseInt(adapter.getItem(position).toString());

                setRadios(TYPE);

            }
```

Comment: although your code makes sense, it still unfortunately doesn't solve my problem of adding RadioButtons.

Comment: Set Radio Button id

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your `for` loop change this `for(int i=0; i==mk; i++)` to this `for(int i=0; i<=mk; i++)` and also you can simplify how you get `int Type` to `int Type = items[position]`